# How can i create new blade in laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I just started using laravel and created a new login page. My issue is how can i create new blade.php file. When I copy the old one, my CSS file is used in the `body`. I want to make a new blade file. Also, can anyone suggest the best way to make login page.

```
<html>
<head>

{!! HTML::style('css/main.css') !!}

</head>


<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,300italic,400italic,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.1.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<body>
<div class="form">

      <ul class="tab-group">
        <li class="tab active"><a href="#signup">Sign Up</a></li>
        <li class="tab"><a href="#login">Log In</a></li>
      </ul>

      <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="signup">   
          <h1>Sign Up for Free</h1>

          <form action="/" method="post">

          <div class="top-row">
            <div class="field-wrap">
              <label>
                First Name<span class="req">*</span>
              </label>
              <input type="text" required autocomplete="off" />
            </div>
```

Comment: just create a new file in views folder and name it something like this somefilename.blade.php

Answer (score 0):

Blade templates are found on Resources/views folder. As suggested in the comment you just create a new file then add `.blade.php` extension to it.

blade files use html and if your comfortable with html5 tackle task as if you were writing plain html.
To get you started check this out http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed `laravelcollective/html`
 Follow the below steps,

1. add `"laravelcollective/html": "5.1.*"` in the require feild inside composer.json file in the root of the project.
2. Run `composer update` from root of your project. This will install the package required for **blade templating** by laravel.
3. In config/app.php, under `providers` add    `Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class`.
4. In config/app.php, under `aliases`  add `'Form'=>Collective\Html\FormFacade::class` and
      `'Html'=>Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class`.

Thankyou :)